# Azure pipelines Secret Variables don't work on PR triggers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a an azure pipelines with a secret variable that triggers on Pull requests.  When triggered the secret variable is not available to the pipeline.

Secret Variable works when triggered by commits to a branch.

pipeline

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
    - '*'

jobs:
- job:
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  timeoutInMinutes: 360
  displayName: 'Running test'
  steps:
  - bash: |
      if [ -z "$(system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri)" ]
      then
        python3 runTest.py \
          --config "blessedImageConfig-temp.json" \
          --code $(SecretCode)
      else
        python3 runTest.py \
          --config "blessedImageConfig-temp.json" \
          --pullRepo $(system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri) \
          --pullId $(system.pullRequest.pullRequestNumber) \
          --code $(SecretCode)
      fi
```

[Secret variable added via the webUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNCSJ.png)

output and error

```
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/95f6ae7c-d2e1-4ebd-891c-2d998eb4b1d9.sh
/home/vsts/work/_temp/95f6ae7c-d2e1-4ebd-891c-2d998eb4b1d9.sh: line 7: SecretCode: command not found
usage: runTest.py [-h] [--config CONFIG] [--code CODE] [--pullId PULLID]
                  [--pullRepo PULLREPO]
runTest.py: error: argument --code: expected one argument
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
```

Comment: Does my answer give you any help to solve the issue? Feel free to share the latest status of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SecretCode: command not found

This error caused by it's a secret variable, and it was passed in command line with the incorrect way.

You may feel confused about this. But, in fact, Microsoft ever warning about this with [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) : **Never pass secrets on the command line.** That's by designed.

I ever meet this similar issue on my docker build. I solved it with mapping the secrets variable value into an environment variable, which also mentioned on the doc of [Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables).

For your **Bash** task, there also has the solution about secret variable: **Use the environment variables input to pass secret variables to this script' and set targetType == Inline is necessary**.

So, you can add the script below into your **Bash task script**, to map the secret variable into the environment variable:

```
inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    - script: 
      echo $code 
      env: 
        code: $(SecretCode)
```